# Losing headers along async task in asp.net web API

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am using Async endpoints for my API,  and sending a token with my requests.
but it seems to be hit or miss on if the token is there,   It feels like the authorisation is sometimes knocked onto a separate thread, and is not passed over the headers and original context that it is working for:

this is what I have by example:

```
public async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (Session = WebApiApplication.Store.OpenAsyncSession())
        {

            try
            {
                var ctr = controllerContext.Controller.ToString();

                if (ctr.Contains("Authorise") || ctr.Contains("ScheduledTask"))
                {
                    var result = await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
                    return result;
                }

                AuthUser = await GetAuthAsync();

                if (AuthUser == null)
                {
                    var r = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(@"Access is denied to this resource, Unable to read a valid access token!"), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden };
                    return r;
                }

                curUser = await GetCurUser(AuthUser);

                if (curUser != null)
                {
                    if (curUser.Id != null)
                    {
                        var user = await Session.LoadAsync<Users>(curUser.Id, cancellationToken);

                        if (user == null || !user.Login.UserEnabled)
                        {
                            var r = new HttpResponseMessage {Content = new StringContent(@"Access is denied to this resource, please pass a valid authorisation token!"), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden};
                            return r;
                        }

                        var result = await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);

                        await Session.SaveChangesAsync();
                        return result;
                    }

                    var rs1 = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(@"Access is denied to this resource, please pass a valid authorisation token!"), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden };
                    return rs1;
                }

                var rs = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(@"Access is denied to this resource, no current user can be found!"), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden };
                return rs;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var rs = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(@"Access is denied to this resource, an error happened when trying to validate: " + ex.Message), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden };
                return rs;
            }
        }
    }
```

this code is essentially to intercept all request, check token, check user and make sure someone has not disabled there account.

The following two are the getAuthAsync and GetCurUser functions:

```
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public async Task<AuthedUser> GetAuthAsync()
    {
        var header = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-access-token"];

        if (header != null)
        {
            var answer = await Task.Run(() => new AuthedUser(header));

            AuthUser = answer;
            curUser = AuthUser.AuthorisedUser.Details.User;

            return answer;
        }

        return new AuthedUser(null);
    }

    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public async Task<Users> GetCurUser(AuthedUser auth)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => auth.AuthorisedUser.Details.User);
    }
```

it appears to be this line  that is causing issues:

```
var header = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-access-token"];
```

Despite the header being sent, and this code working 90%  of the time, sometimes the header is not,  hence my reason for thinking that the code is thrown onto another thread without this information, but only sometimes ( as in when the stack feels like creating a new thread ).

I could be totally wrong,  I just don't know,   I have tried loads of things and can never seem to get around this one issue.

Please review and advise

thought it might be useful to also include this

```
public AuthedUser(string token)
    {
        ProcessToken(token);
    }

    public void ProcessToken(string token)
    {
        try
        {
           // AuthorisedUser = new AuthModel {Details = new AuthExtended(), UserId = ""};

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                AuthorisedUser = new AuthModel
                {
                    Details = new AuthExtended { FingerPrint = null, User = new Users() },
                    UserId = null
                };
            }


            //decrypt token to normal base
            var preAuth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PreAuthModel>(_secure.Decrypt(token));

            //now we need to create the authorised user
            AuthorisedUser = new AuthModel
            {
                UserId = preAuth.UserId
            };

            //need to get the secret from user
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(preAuth.UserId))
            {
                using (Session = WebApiApplication.Store.OpenSession())
                {
                    // get the user, incase any changes have happened like de-authed, roles changed / created
                    var user = Session.Load<Users>(preAuth.UserId);

                    // populate user from token
                    AuthorisedUser.Details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthExtended>(Security.DecryptToken(preAuth.EncryptedUser, user.Login.SecurityKey));

                    //check that the user in token, is the user we collected
                    if (AuthorisedUser.Details.User.Login.SecurityKey == user.Login.SecurityKey && AuthorisedUser.Details.User.Login.Id == user.Login.Id)
                    {
                        AuthorisedUser.Details.User = user;
                        WebApiApplication.AuthorisedUser = AuthorisedUser;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AuthorisedUser.Details = new AuthExtended { FingerPrint = null, User = new Users() };
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AuthorisedUser = new AuthModel
            {
                Details = new AuthExtended { FingerPrint = null, User = new Users() },
                UserId = null
            };
        }
    }
```

I am never really able to step through this, it bounces all over the place
and returns null when header is present, seems to loop and hop all over itself and wipe out the data ?!!

Comment: Why are you calling `Task.Run` in `GetAuthAsync`?

Comment: becase auth.AuthorisedUser.Details.User  is not an async method, its sync, but needing to be async so that i dont bounce out of the async method.   when i call it as a normal sync method, the async function just returns without waiting for the sync method,  so i am wrapping in task to make it wait for my sync method to finish

Comment: `Taks.Run` will sechedule that code to run on the thread pool. The same thread pool the handles HTTP requests. By doing that, you're forcing thread/context switches with no benefit at all, thus hindering performance for that request and the whole application. You're methods don' need to be `async` to return a `Task`/`Task<T>`. It would be much better if you had your method synch and return a `Task` from `Task.FromResult. That `Task` will be completed and will not cause a thread/context switch.

Comment: I did try as sync, at first, but my async code in the API endpoints would run before the sync method had finished,  hence the reason to port into async too.  to be honest, at first initially I had properties for currentUSer, that would be exposed, to any controller that had baseController, as its base.   but like i said, it was then sync, and my async web api endpoints would sometimes not get the details back in time.   Gonna have to redesign my token handler I think,

Comment: read between the lines on your advice, and did sync versions for ExecuteAsync  and then for the rest, did a fall back incase async failed in some way, that allowed me to then just return the normal sync method and fix the results.  Everything is proper stable now, so thanks for the advice,  I think there is still some clean up to go,   sometimes, despite my best clean up efforts, I loose the data, but have a fallback for that now too